# Calling Phpfox::getBlock into template file in PHPFOX

Tags: php, html, phpfox

Today I am trying to call Phpfox::getBlock into the template file in PHPfox but its not working. Please have a look where is problem.

want to add a php Block

```
core.template-copyright
```

into the file

```
register.html.php
```

I tried to add like this

```
{Phpfox::getBlock('core.template-copyright')}
```

But its not working for me even the file (register.html.php) color changed to red in the admincp template editor its mean there is something wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can call phpfox block in template file by using following syntax

{module name='core.template-copyright'}

{module name='module-name.block-name'}

or if you want to add only html file in to template then you should write

{template file='user.block.register.step2'}
```